# Google Analytics API calculation in post request

Tags: api, google-analytics

Post request (Google Analytics API), https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet

```
  "reportRequests":[
   {
    "viewId":"XXX",
    "dateRanges":[
    {
      "startDate":"2021-07-01",
      "endDate":"2021-07-31"
    }, 
    {
      "startDate":"2020-07-01",
      "endDate":"2020-07-31"
    }], 
     "metrics":[
    {
      "expression":"ga:sessions"
    },
    {
      "expression":"(ga:transactionRevenue+ga:goal1Value)/(ga:adCost)"
    },
     {
      "expression":"ga:adCost"
    }],
    "dimensions": [
    {
      "name":"ga:medium"
    }],
      "dimensionFilterClauses": [
                {"filters": [
                    {"dimensionName": "ga:medium",
                     "operator": "EXACT",
                     "expressions": ["cpc"]}
                ]}
            ]
  }]
}
```

I have have added a calculation in one of the metrics

```
{
          "expression":"(ga:transactionRevenue+ga:goal1Value)/(ga:adCost)"
        }
```

Works fine, but the response return a value without decimals? Here 3, but the calculated values for this expression should have been 3.55.

275054+111395 / 108877.35 =  3.549

Possible to get response value included decimals

Response

```
    "metricHeaderEntries": [
                    {
                        "name": "ga:sessions",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "(ga:transactionRevenue+ga:goal1Value)/(ga:adCost)",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ga:adCost",
                        "type": "CURRENCY"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "cpc"
                    ],
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "values": [
                                "37692",
                                "3",
                                "108877.35"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "values": [
                                "35388",
                                "9",
                                "59056.27"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
      "expression":"(ga:transactionRevenue+ga:goal1Value)/(ga:adCost)",
      "formattingType":"FLOAT"
    },
```

Solved